# pass data from the action layer to the model

Tags: model-view-controller, symfony1, doctrine, dql

I have an DQL query in LocationTable.class.php

For this query i need an id which is passed to the action via the URL ?id=2

In the action i can access this with $request->getParamater('id'), but how can i also make this available to the model where my query resides? i need it for a where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the function from the action, pass it the variable:

In action:

```
Doctrine::getTable('Location')->yourFunction($request->getParameter('id'));
```

In LocationTable:

```
public function yourFunction($id)
{
  ...
```